# A question on strongly convex rational polyhedral cone

Tags: convex-geometry

Let A be a strongly convex rational polyhedral cone in R^n.
Does (A+(-A))⋂Z^n=(A⋂Z^n)+(-A⋂Z^n) hold?
If it holds, why does it hold?.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "a strongly convex rational polyhedral cone"?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the equality holds. First note that $A + (-A) = \mathrm{span}_\mathbb{R}(A)$. Indeed, the inclusion $\subseteq$ is clear, and for the other inclusion note that any finite $\mathbb{R}$-linear combination of elements of $A$ can be ordered (according to the sign of the coefficients) into the difference $\alpha - \beta$ between two positive linear combinations. Since $A$ is a convex cone, it is invariant under positive linear combinations, so $\alpha, \beta \in A$.

To finish, it remains to show that $(A \cap \mathbb{Z}^n) + (-A \cap \mathbb{Z}^n) = \mathrm{span}_\mathbb{R}(A) \cap \mathbb{Z}^n$, with the inclusion $\subseteq$ again being obvious. Note that $L=\mathrm{span}_\mathbb{R}(A) \cap \mathbb{Z}^n$ is a finitely generated lattice, isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^d$ where $d = \dim \mathrm{span}_\mathbb{R}(A)$.

**Claim:** We can choose $e$ elements $B$ of $A$ that form a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis of $L$.

If this claim is true, it finishes the proof: any element of $L$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combination of elements in $B$, and grouping the terms with positive and negative coefficients together writes it as an element of $(A \cap \mathbb{Z}^n) + (-A \cap \mathbb{Z}^n)$.

**Proof of claim:** Choose any element $v_1 \in \mathrm{relint}(A) \cap \mathbb{Z}^n$ in the relative interior of $A$. By possibly dividing $v_1$ by a positive integer, we may assume that $v_1$ is primitive. Then extend it to a basis $B' = \{v_1, w_2, \ldots, w_e\}$ of $L$ (which is possible by
[the assumption of $v_0$ being primitive](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4400367/proof-that-any-element-of-a-free-abelian-group-which-is-not-divisible-by-any-k)). Then for a sufficiently large $b \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ we have that all vectors $v_j = w_j + b \cdot v_1$ are still contained in $A$ (since $v_1$ is in the relative interior of $A$). Then $B=\{v_1, \ldots, v_e\}$ is still a basis of $L$ (since we obtained it from $B'$ by adding multiples of one of the elements to the others) and all of its members are contained in $A$. This finishes the proof of the claim.